# VB 6.0 SavePicture Method Problem

Tags: image, forms, vb6

I am using the following code to save an image created on a Form to a bitmap file:

```
SavePicture Form1.Image, Output_Dir + Patternname + ".bmp"
DoEvents
```

Now the image created on the form is a 1600x1200 pixel image (which looks correct); 
however, when I save the file using the above code the image is always saved as a 1920x1200 pixel bitmap.

1920x1200 is the current resolution of my screen.

Here is the code used to set the width/height of the form image:

```
Form1.ScaleMode = vbPixels 
Form1.AutoRedraw = True
W = 1600
H = 1200
Form1.Width = W * Screen.TwipsPerPixelX
Form1.Height = H * Screen.TwipsPerPixelY
Form1.Show
```

I cannot seem to understand why the form image looks correct at 1600x1200, yet when I save the program adds an extra white block of 320X1200 to make the bitmap 1920x1200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you're setting the size of the *form* Form1.  You need to be changing the size of a *picturebox* on the form.  Make sure you have a PictureBox control ("Picture1") on your form, and try this:

```
Picture1.ScaleMode = vbPixels ' Set scale to pixels.
Picture1.AutoRedraw = True    ' If needed

Picture1.Width = W   ' in pixels
Picture1.Height = H  ' in pixels
```

Then save it with this:

```
SavePicture Picture1.Image, Output_Dir + Patternname + ".bmp"
```

Comment: Yes that seems to have solved my problems.  Thank you kind sir.